# Extracting points from a (FIRMS)Google Earth Engine layer in Python

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, pandas, google-earth-engine-python-api, folium

My goal is to extract data from FIRMS to further analyze it in a tabular data format.

How can I extract those orange marks that indicate fire?

Can I output them as a CSV or a pandas dataframe?
I would like something with the following columns [fire_id, lat, long, date]

```py
import ee
import pandas as pd
import folium
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ee.Initialize()
def add_ee_layer(self, ee_image_object, vis_params, name):
    map_id_dict = ee.Image(ee_image_object).getMapId(vis_params)
    folium.raster_layers.TileLayer(
        tiles=map_id_dict["tile_fetcher"].url_format,
        attr='Map Data &copy; <a href="https://earthengine.google.com/">Google Earth Engine</a>',
        name=name,
        overlay=True,
        control=True,
    ).add_to(self)


folium.Map.add_ee_layer = add_ee_layer

firms = (
    ee.ImageCollection("FIRMS")
    .filterDate("2021-08-01", "2021-10-30")
    .select("T21", "confidence", "line_number")
    .mosaic()
)

# Define a map centered on India
mapa = folium.Map(location=[22.369085, 79.893286], zoom_start=10)

fireVis = {
    "bands": ["T21"],
    "gamma": 0.95,
    "min": 300.0,
    "max": 509.29,
}
# Add the image layer to the map and display it.
mapa.add_ee_layer(firms, fireVis, "FIRMS")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a date, you'll need to add a date band to each image before you mosaic.

```
def addYMD(image):
    date = ee.Number.parse(image.date.format('YYYYMMdd'))
    return image.addBands(ee.Image.constant(date).rename('date'))

firms = (ee.ImageCollection("FIRMS")
    .filterDate("2021-08-01", "2021-10-30")
    .select("T21", "confidence", "line_number")
    .map(addYMD)
    .mosaic())
```

If you're just trying to get a csv of all the pixels, you can run `sample` on the image with an added `pixelLonLat` band.

```
projection = ee.ImageCollection("FIRMS").first().select("T21").projection()
table = (firms.addBands(ee.Image.pixelLonLat())
    .sample(region= geometry, projection= projection}))
print(table.getDownloadURL({
  format: "csv"
}))
```

You can also get the image as a numpy array directly, using image.getDownloadURL, although I'm not entirely sure what happens to masked pixels.  I *think* it properly discards them.

```
print(firms.addBands(ee.Image.pixelLonLat()).getDownloadURL({
  region: geometry,
  projection: projection,
  format: "npy"
}))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're just downloading the data, why would you go to Earth Engine to convert raster data to a table, when the original data ingested into Earth Engine was already tabular?

https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/active_fire/

Comment: Many thanks! Well spotted. But this is a vanilla code snippet from a larger automation. I am failing to tabularize back this image. Any tips? Or other posts that had this similar problem in python?